# Smooth corners for a geodesic?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, curve, polyline

I have a page that allows for drawing a polyline with an origin, destination and some waypoints. The context is drawing ship routes.

I currently represent the route as a L.Geodesic :
[image]

But whenever I want to draw intricate routes (going out of port for example) I currently have very pointy angles:
[image]

I have found some leaflet modules that provide a Bézier curve, but nothing that would keep the geodesic aspect.

Is there any leaflet module that would provide curved corners at waypoints while keeping the geodesic aspect for the long straight bits ?

Ideally looking something like that : [image]

This is the current code that draws the polyline (and redraws it whenever a waypoint is added/moved) :

```js
function refreshPolyline() {
    map.removeLayer(geodesic);
    geodesic = new L.Geodesic(points, { className: "polyline ferryPolyline pastPolyline", wrap:false, steps:8 }).addTo(map);
    geodesic.on('click', function (e) {
    var waypointMarker = L.marker(e.latlng, {draggable: true}).addTo(map);
    waypointMarkers.push(waypointMarker);

    var clickedPoint = e.latlng;
    var closestSegmentIndex = getClosestSegmentIndex(points, clickedPoint);
    
    // Insert the new point in the middle of the closest segment
    points.splice(closestSegmentIndex + 1, 0, clickedPoint);
    segmentIndices.push(closestSegmentIndex + 1);

    waypointMarker.on('dragend', function () {
        var marker = this;
        var position = marker.getLatLng();
        var markerIndex = waypointMarkers.indexOf(marker);

        // Update the corresponding point in the points array
        points[segmentIndices[markerIndex]] = position;
        
        // Refresh the polyline
        refreshPolyline();
    });
    });


      distance = 0;
      for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) { 
        distance += getDistanceFromLocations(points[i-1], points[i]);
      }
     content = `<h4>${origLabel} to ${destLabel}</h4>`;
     km = mToKm(distance);
     sailingTime = (distance / 30) * 3.6;
     time = secondsToDhm(sailingTime, "{{langId}}");
       content += `<p><i>${km} km, ${time}</i></p>`;
       content += `<p><button id="saveTrip" type="button" onclick="saveTrip()"> Submit </button></p>`;
  
     
    newTrip["trip_length"] = distance;
    newTrip["estimated_trip_duration"] = sailingTime;
    path = geodesic.getLatLngs()[0];
    console.log(path)
      sidebar.setContent(content);
}
```

(Any other comment to improve that code is welcome, btw)

Comment: What should it look like instead? (can you add an image of what result you want instead, in addition to what it currently looks like?) Because the only way to draw a polygon (or geodesic) from one marker to the next is to do exactly that: draw lines from one marker to the next. If the markers don't line up, you get abrupt changes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, ideally it would use the waypoints as a the basis of a Bézier Curve, like something like [that](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courbe_de_B%C3%A9zier#/media/Fichier:Bezier.gif). 

Also ideally, it would only apply the Bézier around the waypoint, and keep the geodesic shape when there is a long stretch of straight line.

Comment: Leaflet doesn't have those built in, so you'll need to find a plugin that adds the curve type you need such as [Leaflet.Curve](https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve)